# Почему выскакивает ошибка во время исполнения?

Tags: java

Условие задачи:

> Дан упорядоченный по неубыванию массив целых
>   32-разрядных чисел. Требуется удалить из него все повторения.
>   Желательно получить решение, которое не считывает входной файл целиком
>   в память, т.е., использует лишь константный объем памяти в процессе
>   работы. Формат ввода Первая строка входного файла содержит
>   единственное число n, n ≤ 1000000. На следующих n строк расположены
>   числа — элементы массива, по одному на строку. Числа отсортированы по
>   неубыванию. Формат вывода Выходной файл должен содержать следующие в
>   порядке возрастания уникальные элементы входного массива.

Есть код, который при запуске в IDEA не выдаёт никаких ошибок:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Zad3 {
    private static int count_mass = 11;                                               //  Длина считываемого числа

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int size;
        byte o_el[] = new byte[] {11,11,11,11,11,10};       //  предыдущее считанное значение
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            byte el[] = new byte[count_mass];
            size = System.in.read(el);
            if(!eq_mass(el, o_el)){
                System.out.write(el,0,size);
                o_el = el;
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }

    //  Блок функций ------------------------------


    static boolean eq_mass(byte[] m1, byte[] m2){                                   //  Сравнить массив
        boolean rez = true;                                                         //  по умолчанию массивы равны
        for (int i = 0; i < count_mass; i++) {
            if(m1[i] != m2[i]){
                rez = false;
            }
            if (m1[i] == 10 || m2[i] == 10){
                break;
            }
        }
        return rez;
    }
}
```

Если код запустить в системе: https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/8458/problems/C
то он выдаст RE(ошибку во время исполнения), из-за чего это происходит?

Comment: А какое условие задачи? По ссылке нужна регистрация.

Comment: Условие задачи: Дан упорядоченный по неубыванию массив целых 32-разрядных чисел. Требуется удалить из него все повторения.

Желательно получить решение, которое не считывает входной файл целиком в память, т.е., использует лишь константный объем памяти в процессе работы.

Формат ввода
Первая строка входного файла содержит единственное число n, n ≤ 1000000.

На следующих n строк расположены числа — элементы массива, по одному на строку. Числа отсортированы по неубыванию.

Формат вывода
Выходной файл должен содержать следующие в порядке возрастания уникальные элементы входного массива.